# Is it possible to redirect file descriptor 3 to a variable?

Tags: bash, variables, file-descriptor, io-redirection

```
function f()
{
    echo "normal message" >&1
    echo "error message" >&2
    echo "special message" >&3
}
```

Is it possible to call `f` in such a way that stdout and stderr are not redirected at all and output of file descriptor 3 is stored in a variable? I know it's possible when using a temp file:

```
f 3> /tmp/file
variable=$(cat /tmp/file)
```

But is it possible without a temp file?

Comment: Something like `result=$(f 3>&1 1>&2)` maybe? That redirects fd 3 to stdout, and stdout to stderr, so (a)  `special message` is captured in the variable `$result` and (b) you still see both `normal message` and `error message`, although they both appear on stderr.

Comment: @larsks Yeah, exactly as you said, it's almost what I'm looking for except stdout and stderr have to "share" and I'd like them separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to call f in such a way that stdout and stderr are not redirected at all and output of file descriptor 3 is stored in a variable?

No. You can't redirect a file descriptor to a variable, cause then the variable content would have to get modified in mids of another process execution, concurrently to what the current shell is doing. Ie. you could do it with another process that would stream data read from the file descriptor into some shared memory between that process and shell, and the shell then would read that shared memory content when expanding the variable. I believe you could patch `bash` to support such setup.

But do a function anyway instead of hardcoding `>&3`:

```
log() {
    variable+="$("$@")"$'\n'
}
log echo "special message"
```

or better (or worse) if you intent to execute the process in the current shell, not in a subshell:

```
log() {
   logtmpfile=$(tmpfile)
   "$@" > "$logtmpfile"
   variable+="$(<"$logtmpfile")"$'\n'
   rm "$logtmpfile"
}
```

> But is it possible without a temp file?

It's better not to. A file is the simplest way to synchronize between asynchronous processes. (There is a hacky-hacky approach that depends on buffering in pipes `exec 3<> >(sleep infinity); echo 123 >&3; timeout 0.1 cat <&3` but it will fail/block in unexpected ways).

Comment: I mean I know that file descriptors (even 0 - 2) used files underneath so either way I'm using files anyway. So I guess what I was really asking was whether there's any syntactic sugar in bash that lets me avoid using files explicitly. Apparently not. Thanks for the remarks.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found this syntax:

```
{ variable=$(f 4>&1 1>&3 3>&4); } 3>&1
```

which seems to get the result I wanted.

Of course, the way I phrased my question: "in such a way that stdout and stderr are not redirected at all" doesn't apply here but what I really wanted was just stdout and stderr on separate file descriptors. For that reason I'll leave KamilCuk's answer as accepted but I wanted to post this here in case anyone else needs it.